# Check if roots are checked Treeview VBA

Tags: excel, vba, treeview

I am trying to check if a root of my treeview are checked. I don't care if a child is check.

This is my code :

```
If (TreeView.Nodes.Count > 0) Then
Dim check As Boolean
check = False
Set nd = TreeView.Nodes(1).Root.FirstSibling
    Do Until nd Is Nothing
        If nd.Parent Is Nothing And (nd.Selected) Then
            check = True
            MsgBox " a root is checked !"
        End If
        Set nd = nd.Next
    Loop
End If
If Not check Then
       MsgBox "No root checked !"
End If
```

When nothing is checked the code works. But when a child a checked it tells me that a root is checked...
I really don't know how to change that !

Comment: If nd.Parent Is Nothing And (nd.Checked) Then the problem comes from here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You check `.Selected` instead of `.Checked` so change to:

```
If nd.Parent Is Nothing And (nd.Checked) Then
```

Or how about:

```
Dim nd As Node, isCheckedRoot As Boolean
For Each nd In TreeView.Nodes
    If nd.Parent Is Nothing And nd.Checked Then
        isCheckedRoot = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next

MsgBox IIf(isCheckedRoot, "a root is", "No root") & " Checked"
```